# i am trying to deploy pod of kafka on my kubernetes cluster and it not running

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, minikube

when trying to create a kapka pod on my kubrntes its sayms like its connecting for a short amount of time and disconnecting

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: zookeeper
  name: zookeeper-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper
        name: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: zookeeper
          image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
          env:
            - name: "ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT"
              value: "2181"
            - name: "ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME"
              value: "2000"
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 2181
  selector:
    app: zookeeper
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka
  name: kafka-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
        name: kafka
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka
          image: wurstmeister/kafka
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: KAFKA_PORT
              value: "9092"  
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: 10.102.191.88:2181
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
            - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
            - name: KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
              value: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
            - name: KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME
              value: PLAINTEXT
            - name: KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR
              value: "1"
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 9092
  selector:
    app: kafka
```

tried different configurations

Comment: What exactly is failing? You need to show `kubectl logs` output

Answer (score 0):

1. Kafka nor Zookeeper are HTTP services. Remove `name: http` from your ports to not confuse yourself and others.
2. `KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT` should not use IP addresses. [Learn how DNS in Kubernetes works.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)
3. `wurstmeister/*` images are not designed to run in Kubernetes, IMO. Use a Helm Chart or Operator that is known to work without much extra configuration and is widely supported, such as [Strimzi](https://strimzi.io)